# What does following c Macro declaration mean?

Tags: c, macros

As the following c code:

```
#define __xstr(s) __str(s)
#define __str(s) #s
```

what does #s mean?

Comment: Unless it's part of the implementation, it has undefined behavior. Identifiers starting with two underscores, or with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter, are reserved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the [Stringification operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Token_stringification):

> The # operator (known as the "Stringification Operator") converts a token into a string, escaping any quotes or backslashes appropriately.
>
> Example:

```
#define str(s) #s

str(p = "foo\n";) // outputs "p = \"foo\\n\";"
str(\n)           // outputs "\n"
```

> If you want to stringify the expansion of a macro argument, you have to use two levels of macros:

```
#define xstr(s) str(s)
#define str(s) #s
#define foo 4

str (foo)  // outputs "foo"
xstr (foo) // outputs "4"
```

The code in the last sample is very close to the code in the question. Please be aware, as **@KeithThompson** mentioned, that "*identifiers starting with two underscores, or with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter, are reserved*".

Answer (score 0):

The macros allows to do *stringification*, that is convert a macro argument into a string:

`__xstr(foo)` yields `"foo"`

`__xstr(4)` yields   `"4"`

and

`#define BLA bar`

`__xstr(BLA)` yields   `"bar"`

You need two levels of macros to achieve this, see here for more info:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html